# ubuntu 16.04 - Wireless keeps getting dropped after about 2 hours

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, adapter

I have recently installed ubuntu 16 over my 14 install. Now every 2 - 3 hours the connection to the Router gets dropped. And it won't reconnect automatically, it tries too but doesn't.

Also, at the same time, I am on my windows 10 laptop, and the internet works perfectly.

Comment: Are you using dinamic or static IP?

Comment: The default. If that helps?

Comment: Ok. I would suggest using static IP just to verify that the problem is not related with a bad working DHCP client. I mean, configure static IP and see if the problem is still appearing or not.

Comment: I tried, but it says in ifconfig and when i use (ifconfig wlan0 | grep mask) That wlan0 doesn't exist

Comment: Maybe it has a different name. Use `ifconfig` alone a see the interfaces you have. An alternative is to use the GUI to configure wireless connection.

Comment: Well, thanks, even though it went to shit. The Internet hasn't dropped since. something must of worked, so ill update, in a few days. thanks again